# How to delay event processing with Apache Flink

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, delay, delayed-job

I have a requirement to delay processing of some of the events.

eg. I have three events (Consumer Kafka):

```
A (id: 1, retryAt: now)
B (id: 2, retryAt: 15 minutes later)
C (id: 3, retryAt: now)
```

I need to process record A and C immediately, while record B needs to be processed 15 minutes later. Is this something Flink can do?

I have tried to implement the task using KeyedProcessFunction with timers but unfortunate don't work. The event processed is not sent to the destination (sink kafka producer.

The code is the following:

[image]
[image]

Can you help me?

Comment: When you share code on stackoverflow, please post the code as text, rather than as an image.

Comment: @giosefer Please push your code to some GitHub repo so we could check what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Flink's Stateful Functions API (which is designed to make it easier to build event-driven applications with Flink), then support for this is built-in; see [sending delayed messages](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-statefun-docs-stable/docs/sdk/java/#sending-delayed-messages).

With the (lower-level) DataStream API you can use a `KeyedProcessFunction` with timers. You can set a timer for 15 minutes later, and use `MapState<Long, List<Event>>` to remember what you're supposed to do when the timer fires. The map key should be the timestamp of the timer, and the value can be a list of events to process. See [the tutorial on event-driven applications](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/learn-flink/event_driven/) for an example.

Comment: Thanks for your support David! I have tried to implement the task using KeyedProcessFunction with timers but unfortunate don't work. Can you help me? I edit the post with the sample code.

Comment: Event time timers rely on watermarks, which you haven't implemented. Also, I thought you wanted to wait for 15 minutes, but I don't see any code for that. Moreover, I was expecting you would use processing time timers, since it seems like you want to wait for 15 minutes of real time.

Answer (score 0):

Nussknacker implements this functionality as a `Delay` transformation using exactly `KeyedProcessFunction` and `MapState<Long, Lis<Context>>` from DataStream API. Additionally, you are able to specify delay duration. You can check the source code [here](https://github.com/TouK/nussknacker/blob/staging/engine/flink/components/base/src/main/scala/pl/touk/nussknacker/engine/flink/util/transformer/DelayTransformer.scala), its in Scala but should be straightforward to write in Java as you mentioned.

Comment: Thanks for your support dswiecki! I have tried to implement the task using KeyedProcessFunction with timers but unfortunate don't work. Can you help me? I edit the post with the sample code.